# Post request never getting made, just sends get

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose and nodejs to write an API.

My users.js looks as follow:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var user = require('../models/users.js');


router.post('/',function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("made a post");

            var user2 = new user();     // create a new instance of the Bear model
            user2.firstName = req.body.firstName;  // set the bears name (comes from the request)
        user2.lastName=req.body.lastName;
        user2.email=req.body.email;

            user2.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

            console.log("User created");
            });


        })

//The model acts as our user object...this returns all users.
    .get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      console.log("sending a get request");
        user.find(function(err, users) {
           if (err)
               res.send(err);

           res.json(users);
       });

      })

module.exports = router;
```

When I send a get request, it works perfectly. However, I am now trying to develop the POST request. I send a request such as the following:

```
http://localhost:4000/users?firstName=Han&lastName=Bo@email=haBo@yah.com
```

and I receive the following in my console:

```
    sending a get request
GET /users?firstName=Han&lastName=Bo@email=haBo@yah.com
 200 15.522 ms - 1365
```

And I receive the output of my GET request in the browser.

I'm new to node and would appreciate some help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are putting your parameters as URL parameters, while your POST API reads parameters from body of request.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request) is explanation of POST parameters.
Also, if you are not already using it, use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to send requests.

Comment: I was following a tutorial here:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4 and his post request seems to work this way?

Comment: Take a look again, all of the post requests send their data as x-www-form-urlencoded in body of POST request, not as URL Params:
https://cask.scotch.io/2014/04/node-api-postman-post-create-bear.png

Comment: This way of sending parameters is usually used in GET requests because there is no body in GET, only headers.